# Cucumber test with rails 4 throws error: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, cucumber, capybara

```
bundle exec cucumber features/products.feature
```

Using this command I am running my cucumber test for product feature
for all scenario but it throws an error after one scenario executes

```
Given I am an authenticated user #features/step_definitions/login.rb:37
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
    (Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.80)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13.307650 (feffe1dd547ee7b5c16d38784cd0cd679dfd7850),platform=Mac OS X 10.8.5 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError)
```

for authentication. But if I run one by one scenario it succeeds. Please any help how to run all scenario at time with exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes if you look for an element on the page which is not loaded yet or expires because the dom has changed in the previous step. Make sure that when you run the your test cases as bulk each cases should be isolated from others. You should check that the element you want to interact is on the page if not add extra steps to make sure it loads there.

Comment: Can you give any solution, because when one scenario complete it again check for authentication for user. i.e. it again create session.
For each scenario its sign in to the application every time.

Comment: İt always opens a fresh browser that why you need to add each case self employed. Use background option for preparing precondition. I.e if you are logging in for every case you can add it to background.